Firebase and vue - Missing "./compat" specifier in "firebase" package
I don't understand, I'm using firebase, vuefire and vue:
My fstore.js:

function createFirebaseApp() {
  return initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
}

export const fbapp = createFirebaseApp()

export const fb = getFirestore(fbapp)


main.ts:
// Components
import App from './App.vue'

// Composables
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import {fbapp} from "./fstore";



const app = createApp(App)
app.use(VueFire, {
  firebaseApp: fbapp,
  modules: [ VueFireAuth() ]
})
registerPlugins(app)

app.mount('#app')

App.vue:
const googleAuthProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider()
const auth = useFirebaseAuth()
const user = useCurrentUser()
const todos = useCollection(null)

watch(user, (newValue, oldValue) => {
  console.log("old", oldValue);
  console.log("new", newValue);
  const cp = '/data/' + newValue.uid + '/todos'
  const coll = collection(fb, cp)
  // todos = useCollection(fb, cp)
  const d = doc(fb, cp, '1')
  setDoc(
    d,
    {'item': 'Something 1234'} as DocumentReference<DocumentData, DocumentData>)
});

Why am I getting this error? I have no idea why I need the compat stuff, I generated this project with vue and yarn today and created my Google project today, so it's all current.
"dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "6.2.95",
    "firebase": "^10.10.0",
    "roboto-fontface": "*",
    "vue": "^3.4.21",
    "vue-router": "4",
    "vuefire": "^3.1.23",
    "vuetify": "^3.5.8"
  },

I don't even know where to start here, and I have tried importing all kinds of compat stuff but it does not work...
Error:

[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Missing "./compat" specifier in
"firebase" package
/home/mike/IdeaProjects/pm/src/App.vue
at e (file:///home/mike/IdeaProjects/pm/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:47635:25)
at n (file:///home/mike/IdeaProjects/pm/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:47635:627)
at o (file:///home/mike/IdeaProjects/pm/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:47635:1297)
at resolveExportsOrImports (file:///home/mike/IdeaProjects/pm/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:48325:20)
at resolveDeepImport (file:///home/mike/IdeaProjects/pm/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:48344:31)
at tryNodeResolve (file:///home/mike/IdeaProjects/pm/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:48069:20)
at Context.resolveId (file:///home/mike/IdeaProjects/pm/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:47819:28)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async Object.resolveId (file:///home/mike/IdeaProjects/pm/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:51096:32)
at async TransformContext.resolve (file:///home/mike/IdeaProjects/pm/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:50787:23



Please edit the question to be clear about where you are seeing that error, and which line of code causes it, according to your debugging.
